# Webbrowser current URL (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Im working on a project , and i have an obstacle about webbrowser tool in vb.net . I want to show a msgbox when the user is in a specific site , how can this be done ? , in another words , how can  i get the current url in the webberowser tool in vb.net?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't support ="?

Comment: I mean this statment :
if webbrowser1.url = "Http://google.com" then
msgbox "google"
end if
Is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

`Webbrowser.Url` is a `Uri`, not a string. So compare it with a `Uri`.

```
If WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://stackoverflow.com") Then
```

Comment: Gserg , but this code doesn't work , try it .
If WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://stackoverflow.com") Then 
msgbox ("stack")
end if

Comment: Why, [it does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihd3R.png). Do you allow the page to actually load before checking the url?

Comment: To cite the docs: *This property contains the URL of the current document, even if another document has been requested. If you set the value of this property and then immediately retrieve it again, the value retrieved may be different than the value set if the WebBrowser control has not had time to load the new document. You can retrieve the new value in a DocumentCompleted event handler.*

Comment: Try this : Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://google.com") Then
            MsgBox("google")
        End If
It didn't work for me ?  the page 100% loads but it shows no msgbox

Comment: How can the page load before the check if you check in `Form_Load`? You check, then it loads and shows. Before it loads, it's `about:blank`. Use the `DocumentCompleted` event handler as suggested.

Comment: Sorry , i don't get it . I tried to put the above code under webbrowser_documentcompleted , but it doesn't even work ? can you release the full code ?

Comment: I have, on the screenshot. There is a button which I click after I see the page has finished loading. Same would happen if I used `DocumentCompleted` instead. Note `http://` with which the uri begins. You seem to insist on omitting it, you shouldn't.

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically removes the http , I tried to do this as well but it didn't work . May you please upload the source on a site or take screen shot for the code ? because i really need this but it seems it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I would say you should check the Host of the URI, that way it works for all of the URLs and not just the top level for a given site:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1( sender As System.Object,  e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted( sender As System.Object,  e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Url.Host = "stackoverflow.com"
        MessageBox.Show("You are at stack overflow")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir ! it works :) im very thankful for you.

Comment: @user1970090 Since you said this works, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next below the voting icons.  That indicates to others that this is the accepted solution.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you mean?

```
Dim browser As String


    browser = TextBox1.Text
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(browser)

    MsgBox("Your visiting " & browser)

End Sub
```