# How to open an IE popup with no addressbar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to add a button in my application to open a site , I want the site to be opened in POP UP (so the address can't be changed) , How can this be done ?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: VB.NET windows from application .

Answer (score 1):

Add a COM reference to Microsoft Internet Controls to your project.

```
Dim  ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()
ie.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
ie.ToolBar = 0
ie.AddressBar = false
ie.Visible = true
```

While this works, you are stuck with what IE gives you via its COM object.  If you need more control, you can always just use the webbrowser control.

Comment: Thank you very much , but I have a problem with webbrowser , check it please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279094/webbrowser-current-url-vb-net

& It says SHDocVw isn't denified

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create your own form, and drop a WebBrowser control in it.

Comment: I tried , But i have this problem [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279094/webbrowser-current-url-vb-net